# How To Not be in Tornado Alley Anymore

Tags: climate, geography, weather, natural-disasters

I am from northeastern Nebraska, which means I often get concerned about the potential of coming tornadoes.

So what, **geographically**, must I do to put northeastern Nebraska AWAY from Tornado Alley without sacrificing the prairie fertility of the Great Plains in the process?

Comment: What does the prairie fertility have to do with anything regarding tornadoes? Just move both of them away together...

Comment: This is both far too broad, and what is called Idea Generation, both of which are reasons to close the question. You need to develop this and narrow the scope so that it is answerable in a few paragraphs instead of a book.

Comment: You want to move Nebraska or Tornado Alley?

Comment: @Aify  If I change the size of the Rockies, for example, I'd end up either making Tornado Alley more powerful or turning the Great Plains from prairie into desert.  So how do I change North America to move Nebraska away from Tornado Alley and still retain the Plains' prairie fertility?

Comment: @JohnWDailey You need to narrow down what sort of answers you're looking for. Do you want to change weather patterns, change surrounding geography, or pick up and move an entire state?

Comment: Anything to make sure that northeastern Nebraska is OUTSIDE Tornado Alley.

Comment: @JohnWDailey That makes this far too broad. I'd just type on my magic keyboard to stop the tornados.

Comment: @apaul34208  Any suggestions on the geographical end?

Comment: Feel free to edit the question to narrow it down.

Comment: @apaul34208 How?

Comment: Umm? Ask a more specific question. "What geographic changes would I need to make in order to discourage tornadoes from forming near  northeastern Nebraska?" Add some research info on tornado formation, some specific info on why you're doing this, what sort of answers you're looking for... Then you'll have a pretty specific well formed question

Answer (score 1):

IIRC, the reason for tornadoes is because there is a high altitude west to east cold flow and a low altitude south to north flow that is warm and humid. The both flows are nearly laminar and well separated. There is lots of energy in this separation which then is released in the form of tornadoes.

The solution is simple (in **theory**, not practice), you need to create turbulence that mixes the two layers and dissipates the energy without the tornadoes. I think some physicist calculated that a relatively low fence north of the Gulf would create enough turbulence to break the layer separation. Although the meteorologists commenting on the article I read were under the impression the idea was to stop the south to north wind, which is nonsense **and** economically dangerous, so the article lacked any details on the actual effects on the climate.

My understanding at the time was that the physicist used the simple fence because it was the simplest to model. Any structure that creates vertical turbulence over wide area should work, even if it is closer to the target area you want to protect. I think you should be able to combine this with wind power generation. Also it doesn't really matter which of the two flows you disturb. The south to north flow is obviously closer to ground so that is the pick for a simple fence solution, but there are suggestions of airborne wind power solutions that could reach the high flow and could probably be adapted for tornado prevention.

Just to be clear, the idea is not to stop either of the flows, just to break the layer separation with turbulence. There is too much energy in the system for stopping it to be practical or safe, but with turbulence the same energy can be used to break the layer separation. And "no separate layers" -> "less tornadoes".

Comment: Do such fences exist elsewhere in the world?  I'm having a hard time following your example.

Comment: @JohnWDailey Not that I know of. It is something I read in an article I can't find few years ago. Do not remember the name of the person who suggested it either. And as I implied the article almost certainly had the original idea totally wrong, since what the article claimed was nonsense. Still the basic concept of using turbulence to mix the layers should be solid enough.

Answer (score 0):

Tornadoes come from thunderstorms, the cold and warm fronts that make them build during the long straight ride from the Rockies to the east, unobstructed by terrain.

Mountain chains break up this process.  Put an extra mountain chain in West Nebraska and you will most of that.  Of course, there go your crops, but the skiing is better.

Comment: I think that sacrifices the "prairie fertility" he required.

Comment: You can't make an omelet without breaking eggs.

Comment: I've always liked toast more. Seriously, though, it's a big concession.

Comment: Maybe an inland sea in place of the Rockies would work.  Then you lose the *Prairie*, as it would be jungle, but not the *Fertility*.  Without resorting to magic, I think the tornado and plains go together as the way flat spaces and temperate zone weather work.